# NSOperation hierarchy, units of work

Tags: ios, nsoperation

So I was wondering what the best way to break out long tasks into NSOperations.  If I have 3 long running tasks, is it better to have one NSOperation subclass that basically does something like

```
Single NSOperation subclass
- (void)main {
  // do long running task 1
  // do long running task 2
  // do long running task 3

  // call back the delegate
}
```

Or is it better to have each task be a subclass of NSOperation, and then manage each task from my ViewController as a single unit of work?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you ever need to do any of the tasks independent of the others? Should the tasks be run in parallel or strictly in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether the operation queue is serial (i.e. max concurrent operations 1) or parallel, and what the nature of the work is. If the queue is serial, then it really doesn't matter. If the queue is parallel, then it depends on a bunch of factors:

- is the work safe to do concurrently
- does the work contend on a shared resource (such as network or disk IO, or a lock) that would remove the concurrency
- is each unit of work sufficiently large to be worth the overhead of dispatching separately

(edit)

Also, if you don't need the advanced features of NSOperationQueue (operation dependencies and priorities, KVO, etc...), consider using dispatch queues instead. They're significantly lighter weight.